# & escaping as &amp; when hitting Java endpoint

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jaxb

I have a rough understanding of escaping characters and why it's necessary but I don't fully understand how Java handles it with xml and json. I have a request hitting my Java endpoint that gives an object with a string email. If it is an email that contains an & (e.g. em&ail@email.com), it gets to the endpoint as em&ail@email.com. An annotation @valid causes an exception right away because the email has a constraint validator that uses a regex which the email fails due to the ;. This prevents me from just using a changeAll method to switch the & to &. The email is an XML element:

```
@XmlAccessorType(value = XmlAccessType.NONE)
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Customer implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1926491417023377659L;
    @XmlElement
    @Validator
    private String Email;
```

The endpoint has a few annotations as well:

```
@Path("/customer")
@Component
public class CustomerResource{

@POST
@Path("/customers")
@Consumes({ APPLICATION_JSON, APPLICATION_XML })
@Produces({ APPLICATION_JSON, APPLICATION_XML })
public Response createTransaction(@PathParam("id") String Id, @Context SecurityContext securityContext, Customer customer) {
    validateCustomer(Id, customer);
    return CustomerService.createTransaction(customer);
}
```

What is the common practice in java for preventing string characters from escaping?

Comment: Why escaping matters? As xml has a special meaning for < and > symbols you need to have a way to use them by their straight meaning. Escaping is for this, you have a sequence of other symbols to represent < and >

Comment: @ipergenitsa Sorry if I phrased my question badly. I meant I understand why escaping is important, I'm just not sure on the solution for it. Obviously if someone inputs their email in your app and it is sent to your back end through a java service you don't want their email being changed from em&ail@email.com to em&amp;ail@email.com and being saved as that. So what is the most common solution to preventing this?